# Does Oracle allow to do a sum over a partition but only when it obeys certain conditions, otherwise use a lag?

Tags: sql, oracle

So my company has an application that has a certain "in-app currency". We record every transaction.
Recently, we found out there was a bug running for a couple of weeks that allowed users to spend currency in a certain place, even when they had none. When this happened, users wouldn't get charged at all: e.g. User had 4 m.u. and bought something that's worth 10 m.u. it's balance would remain at 4.

Now we need to find out who abused it and what's their available balance.

I want to get the column **BUG_ABUSE** and **WISHFUL_CUMMULATIVE** that reflect the illegitimate transactions and the amount that our users really see in their in-app wallets but I'm running out of ideas of how to get there.

I was wondering if I could do something like a sum(estrelas) if result over 0 else lag over (partition by user order by date) or something of the likes to get the wishful cummulative.

We're using oracle. Any help is highly appreciated

| User_ID | EVENT_DATE | AMOUNT | DIRECTION | RK | CUM | WISHFUL_CUMMULATIVE | BUG_ABUSE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 02/01/2021 13:37:19,009000 | -5 | 0 | 1 | -5 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 08/01/2021 01:55:40,000000 | 40 | 1 | 2 | 35 | 40 | 0 |
| 1 | 10/01/2021 10:45:41,000000 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 37 | 42 | 0 |
| 1 | 10/01/2021 10:45:58,000000 | 2 | 1 | 4 | 39 | 44 | 0 |
| 1 | 10/01/2021 13:47:37,456000 | -5 | 0 | 5 | 34 | 39 | 0 |
| 2 | 13/01/2021 20:09:59,000000 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 2 | 16/01/2021 15:14:54,000000 | -50 | 0 | 2 | -48 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 19/01/2021 02:02:59,730000 | -5 | 0 | 3 | -53 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 23/01/2021 21:14:40,000000 | 3 | 1 | 4 | -50 | 5 | 0 |
| 2 | 23/01/2021 21:14:50,000000 | -5 | 0 | 5 | -55 | 0 | 0 |

Comment: "Abuse" implies that the users did something they weren't supposed to. You said this was a bug (therefore, caused by **your company**). So, don't call it "abuse"; your users didn't even "take advantage" of the bug. They "benefited" from it; it's possible they didn't even realize it either. After all, **you** are the ones who *suffered* from it, and even you didn't notice it for a few days.

Comment: Trying to understand your data (since you didn't think it would help to do so yourself). Are negative numbers "purchases", and positive numbers "deposits"? Is the "direction" column simply a flag, 0 for purchase, 1 for deposit (and therefore, useless duplication of information)? If you flag a purchase as "bug abuse" (note my objection to your terminology, above), do you want to flag that transaction, and to treat the user's wallet balance **as if** that abusive purchase had not been allowed, for purposes of inspecting the remaining transactions?

Comment: Very likely this can all be done in a single SQL query, but you need a very clear description of the problem (something like I wrote in my previous comment) and especially of the desired output. Also very important: What is your Oracle version? (Because different advanced features were introduced in different versions of the database.)

Comment: I agree, the word BUG_ABUSE was just a joke, as it was WISHFUL_CUMMULATIVE.
Some definitely "abused it" by "purchasing" stuff improperly almost 4k times.

The direction column is, indeed, useless duplication of information that I just happened to keep. 

I tought it could be useful to help me visualize with more clarity some solutions that didn't work out.

We're using oracle 12c

Answer (score 1):

Here's something you can try. This uses recursive subquery factoring (recursive WITH clause), so it will only work in Oracle 11.2 and higher.

I use columns USER_ID, EVENT_DATE and AMOUNT from your inputs. I assume all three columns are constrained NOT NULL, two events can't have exactly the same timestamp for the same user, and AMOUNT is negative for purchases and other debits (fees, etc.) and positive for deposits or other credits.

The input data looks like this:

```
select user_id, event_date, amount
from   sample_data
order  by user_id, event_date
;

USER_ID EVENT_DATE                    AMOUNT
------- ----------------------------- ------
      1 02/01/2021 13:37:19,009000000     -5
      1 08/01/2021 01:55:40,000000000     40
      1 10/01/2021 10:45:41,000000000      2
      1 10/01/2021 10:45:58,000000000      2
      1 10/01/2021 13:47:37,456000000     -5
      2 13/01/2021 20:09:59,000000000      2
      2 16/01/2021 15:14:54,000000000    -50
      2 19/01/2021 02:02:59,730000000     -5
      2 23/01/2021 21:14:40,000000000      3
      2 23/01/2021 21:14:50,000000000     -5
```

Perhaps your input data has additional columns (like cumulative amount, which I left out because it plays no role in the problem or its solution). You show a RK column - I assume you computed it as a step in your attempt to solve the problem; I re-create it in my solution below.

Here is what you can do with a recursive query (recursive WITH clause):

```
with
  p (user_id, event_date, amount, rk) as (
    select user_id, event_date, amount,
           row_number() over (partition by user_id order by event_date)
    from   sample_data
  )
, r (user_id, event_date, amount, rk, bug_flag, balance) as (
    select  user_id, event_date, amount, rk,
            case when amount < 0 then 'bug' end, greatest(amount, 0)
      from  p
      where rk = 1
    union all
    select  p.user_id, p.event_date, p.amount, p.rk, 
            case when p.amount + r.balance < 0 then 'bug' end,
            r.balance + case when r.balance + p.amount >= 0
                             then p.amount else 0 end
      from  p join r on p.user_id = r.user_id and p.rk = r.rk + 1
  )
select *
from   r
order  by user_id, event_date
;
```

Output:

```
USER_ID EVENT_DATE                    AMOUNT RK BUG BALANCE
------- ----------------------------- ------ -- --- -------
      1 02/01/2021 13:37:19,009000000     -5  1 bug       0
      1 08/01/2021 01:55:40,000000000     40  2          40
      1 10/01/2021 10:45:41,000000000      2  3          42
      1 10/01/2021 10:45:58,000000000      2  4          44
      1 10/01/2021 13:47:37,456000000     -5  5          39
      2 13/01/2021 20:09:59,000000000      2  1           2
      2 16/01/2021 15:14:54,000000000    -50  2 bug       2
      2 19/01/2021 02:02:59,730000000     -5  3 bug       2
      2 23/01/2021 21:14:40,000000000      3  4           5
      2 23/01/2021 21:14:50,000000000     -5  5           0
```

Comment: Ha! Exact same solution. Due to laziness I assumed `RK` was already computed.

Comment: @TheImpaler - almost. Your solution, in the recursive branch, has `greatest(n.wishful + t.amount, 0)`, which doesn't seem to correspond to anything in the column list - and, instead, is missing the computation of `bug_abuse`.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot! I used your solution, just keeping the rk because it was indeed a  row_number() over (partition by user_id order by event_date asc).

USER_ID, EVENT_DATE and AMOUNT are indeed NOT NULL and a user can't have the same exact event_dates

Answer (score 0):

In order to produce the result you want you'll probably want to process the rows sequentially: once the first row is processed for a user you'll compute the second one, then the third one, and so on.

Assuming the column `RK` is already computed and **sequential** for each user you can do:

```
with
n (user_id, event_date, amount, direction, rk, cum, wishful, bug_abuse) as (
  select t.*,
    greatest(amount, 0),
    case when amount < 0 then 1 else 0 end
  from t where rk = 1
 union all
  select
    t.user_id, t.event_date, t.amount, t.direction, t.rk, t.cum,
    greatest(n.wishful + t.amount, 0),
    case when n.wishful + t.amount < 0 then n.wishful 
                                       else n.wishful + t.amount
    end
  from n
  join t on t.user_id = n.user_id and t.rk = n.rk + 1
)
select *
from n
order by user_id, rk;
```

Comment: hey mate, thanks. this solution is very similar to the one posted by @mathguy , but his would helped me check straight away the bugged transactions so I decided to use his.

I really appreciate your help though!

Comment: @Clean If mathguy's answer is correct, then accept it.